# Por que for loop no duplica el array en el que esta iterando? Esto lo quiero hacer en puro Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bucles

Tengo un `li` en el cual itero para que me saque todos los elementos que tengan la clase `.especial` y los agrupe en un `div` vacío, pero este al hacer el loop, los extrae; no los duplica de la lista ya existente.

Mi código va así:

HTML

```js
let liClassEspecial = document.querySelectorAll("li.especial");
let liArray = Array.from(liClassEspecial);

let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let olElement = document.createElement("ol");
container.appendChild(olElement);

var insert = () => {
  for(i=0; i<=liArray.length; i++){
    try {
       olElement.appendChild(liArray[i]);
    } catch(err) {
       err;
    }
  }
}
insert();
```

```html
<ol class="lista">
  <li>Item-1</li>
  <li class="especial"> Item-2</li>
  <li>Item-3</li>
  <li class="especial">Item-4</li>
  <li>Item-5</li>
  <li class="especial">Item-6</li>
</ol>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Lo he intentado con map() y obtengo el mismo resultado:                           let nuevoArray = liArray.map(function(liArray){
 olElement.appendChild(liArray);
  });

Comment: Cuando quieras meter código Javascript/HTML en una pregunta, te recomiendo usar un fragmento, el acceso rápido es `Ctrl` + `M`.

Comment: En cualquier caso, bienvenida a SOes. Es una buena primera pregunta (bien escrita y detallada). Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bievenida para familiarizarte con el sitio y ganar una medalla extra

Comment: Además puedes visitar [Ayuda de edición de Markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Pero como dice @PabloLozano para ser la primera pregunta es muy buena pregunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si quieres duplicarlos, tienes que decirlo expresamente: Lo que hace tu código es *moverlos* dentro del árbol del DOM, un elemento no puede estar en dos sitios a la vez. Por tanto tienes que [**clonarlos**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```js
let liClassEspecial = document.querySelectorAll("li.especial");
let liArray = Array.from(liClassEspecial);

let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let olElement = document.createElement("ol");
container.appendChild(olElement);

var insert = () => {
  for(i=0; i<=liArray.length; i++){
    try {
       olElement.appendChild(liArray[i].cloneNode(true));
    } catch(err) {
       err;
    }
  }
}
insert();
```

```html
<ol class="lista">
  <li>Item-1</li>
  <li class="especial"> Item-2</li>
  <li>Item-3</li>
  <li class="especial">Item-4</li>
  <li>Item-5</li>
  <li class="especial">Item-6</li>
</ol>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Siii, quedo perfecto !! .. El código quedo así:                                                       var insert = () => {
    for(i=0; i<=liArray.length; i++){
        try {
            var liClone = liArray[i].cloneNode(true);
            olElement.appendChild(liClone);
        } catch(err) {
            err;
        } }}

Comment: Si quieres puedes intentar con mi código, te simplifica muchísimo tu solución, lo único es que necesitas jQuery, y jQuery seguramente te lo haga de una manera más óptima, ya que son funciones y a preparadas.

Answer (score 0):

lo que necesitas es usar la función jquery `clone()`, para tu código serviría lo siguiente:

```
//Recuperamos elementos que tengan la lista y los clonamos.
var elementosClonados = $("li.especial").clone();

//Creamos la lista del div .container
$(".container").append("<ol></ol>");
$(".container ol").append(elementosClonados);
```

La función `clone()` lo que hace es crear una copia (clon) del elemento que seleccionas, lo que tu estabas haciendo era coger ese elemento, por lo tanto lo estabas moviendo de sitio.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: La pregunta especifica puro Javascript (*sin librerías* o "vainilla"), no está usando jQuery